# What is WRAP of OpenCV's CMakeLists.txt used for?

Tags: opencv, cmake

```
ocv_add_module(core PRIVATE_REQUIRED ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} "${OPENCL_LIBRARIES}"
               OPTIONAL opencv_cudev
               WRAP java python)
```

Like the code above, what is `WRAP` used for? What is the relationship between "core" and "java"?

Comment: I think this may create the java and python wrappers for the underlying C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

The variables immediately after `WRAP` list wrappers for the OpenCV module being added.  So, the relationship between "core" and "java" is that there is a Java wrapper for the core module.

The `ocv_add_module` which is defined [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/edb4a7ad03a68353927b6589994126381bb327b2/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake#L127-L131) has the following usage description:

```
ocv_add_module(<name> [INTERNAL|BINDINGS]
               [REQUIRED] [<list of dependencies>]
               [OPTIONAL <list of optional dependencies>]
               [WRAP <list of wrappers>])
```